# How to code a multi-period objective function in Tensorflow 2?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I want to train a neural network f(x,y) so as to minimize an objective function of the form:

G(x_1, x_2, ..., x_N)

where x_{n+1} = f(x_n,y_n) + noise

and y_{n+1} = y_n + noise

How to proceed in tensorflow 2?

When N = 1, I know how to proceed but whenever N>1, the recurrent nature of the problem raises difficulty.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.